# Summing up previous 10 rows of a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm wondering how to sum up 10 rows of a data frame from any point.

I tried using rolling(10,window =1).sum() but the very first row should sum up the 10 rows below. Similar issue with cumsum()

So if my data frame is just the A column, id like it to output B.

```
    A   B
0   10  550
1   20  650
2   30  750
3   40  850
4   50  950
5   60  1050
6   70  1150
7   80  1250
8   90  1350
9   100 1450
10  110 etc
11  120 etc
12  130 etc
13  140 
14  150 
15  160 
16  170 
17  180 
18  190
```

It would be similar to doing this operation in excel and copying it down

Excel Example:

[image: Excel Example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reverse your series before using [`pd.Series.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html), and then reverse the result:

```
df['B'] = df['A'][::-1].rolling(10, min_periods=0).sum()[::-1]

print(df)

      A       B
0    10   550.0
1    20   650.0
2    30   750.0
3    40   850.0
4    50   950.0
5    60  1050.0
6    70  1150.0
7    80  1250.0
8    90  1350.0
9   100  1450.0
10  110  1350.0
11  120  1240.0
12  130  1120.0
13  140   990.0
14  150   850.0
15  160   700.0
16  170   540.0
17  180   370.0
18  190   190.0
```

Comment: Nice solution. I like using the [::-1] reversing element. +1

Comment: this worked well. I'm kinda surprised there isn't a more straight forward way to do this (coming from working with excel a lot). Regardless, thanks so much for the help!